# Crystal Reports XI R2 and Win 7 running 64 bit mode

Tags: crystal-reports

We are reluctant to move to Crystal Reports 2008.  But it appears that that is the only way to get a version of Crystal that is compatible with Windows 7 running in the 64 bit mode.  Does anyone know if SAP is going to retrofit CR XI R2 to run on Win 7 in the 64 bit mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP has confirmed that they will not retrofit CR XI R2 for 64 bit mode.  You have to upgrade to CR 2008.

Answer (score 0):

[You could try stimulsoft reports which have zero foot print like merge modules etc.100% managed and has tool to export crystal report to stimulsoft.](http://stimulsoft.com/)